# Quartz scheduler using cluster with Oracle RAC is giving ORA-12838 exception

Tags: oracle11g, parallel-processing, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler for my batch jobs in clustered mode and my application is using Oracle RAC for load balancing. I am getting the below exception after equal intervals of 4 mins in the logs. Strangely this exception does not come on lower environments where there is just one Oracle server. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
04:56:04,909 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore]
 ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure recovering jobs: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failure recovering jobs: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
 [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterRecover(JobStoreSupport.java:3559) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3270) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3858) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3895) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectInstancesFiredTriggerRecords(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2833) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterRecover(JobStoreSupport.java:3431) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you please share the SQL which is getting the ora-12838 ? I suspect that your code is doing an insert/update with PARALLEL or APPEND hint and then trying to do a SELECT without committing first.